# ABP Problem with loading @abp/ng.identity module

Tags: angular, abp

I have a problem with loading the built-in modules, if I am on a certain route, for example Users, and reload the page, the error crashes

the provided screens show the errors that appear when you go to the users or roles page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfeXd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPF5q.png)

Here is part of my `app-routing.module.ts` routing file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.account').then(m => m.AccountModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'identity',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.identity').then(m => m.IdentityModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'tenant-management',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.tenant-management').then(m => m.TenantManagementModule.forLazy()),
  },
  {
    path: 'setting-management',
    loadChildren: () => import('@abp/ng.setting-management').then(m => m.SettingManagementModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'page-content',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/pages/page-content').then(m => m.PageContentModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'theme',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/pages/theme').then(m => m.ThemeModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'languages',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/pages/languages').then(m => m.LanguagesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'countries',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/pages/countries').then(m => m.CountriesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/pages/users').then(m => m.UsersModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'roles',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/pages/roles').then(m => m.RolesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'media',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/pages/media').then(m => m.MediaModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'menu-section',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/pages/menu-section').then(m => m.MenuSectionModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'categories',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/pages/categories').then(m => m.CategoriesModule),
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```